What is the social meaning of this intermediate formality in "Witness for the Dead"?
The world of The Witness for the Dead and The Goblin Emperor has numerous detailed linguistic elements that support its worldbuilding and are not explicitly explained, such as different name endings to denote marriage or gender, or even whether one is an elf or a goblin. One such element is the use of different pronouns and other devices to denote social registers of different formalities, as in languages such as Japanese.
It seems clear that when talking to someone with whom one shares a great degree of confidence, the characters use "I" to refer to themselves and "thou" to address the person that they are speaking with, as was once the case in English in the real world. When talking to strangers in formal settings, most characters seem to use "we" and "you."
However, there seems to be an intermediate usage where the speaker refers to themself as I (informal) and their conversation partner as you (formal). This is how Celehar speaks with Tomasaran, for instance, but it is not limited to the prelacy—later on, he also speaks to Pel-Thenhior this way, and Pel-Thenhior speaks to him in the same fashion. Celehar also addresses Pel-Venna similarly, and even speaks the same way when talking to the photographer Nathomar. That is to say, this form of address is used both inside and outside the prelacy, with both strangers and friends.
In what type of social contexts can or should one use this type of intermediate formal address? Does it depend on social status, age, gender, elven or goblin status?

Honestly, it's probably just bad editing.

@Raj - Oh, definitely not in this case. It's all very intentional here. There's a short story where a character explicitly forgets to use the formal first-person and uses exactly this intermediate formality.

I agree that it is intentional. I took it as either a way of allowing a relationship to evolve (after all, if a relationship is going to become familiar, someone has to go first) or of implying that the conversation was, in a way, 'off the record'.

@Barnaby - I have come to believe that this represents a situation where something like our modern way of speaking—with "you" and "I"—is starting to displace the formal and intimate registers, the former faster than the latter. The characters we follow are almost all very cultured—priests, nobility—so they do not usually talk informally, and people recognize their formality and respond "politely."

Celehar slips into informal speech with a few people because he is not "on the clock," as it were. It's almost always other priests, Pel-Thenhior, or people he meets with Pel-Thenhior—people he could see as his friends or colleagues rather than people he interacts with as part of his official duties. Later, of course, as his relationship with Pel-Thenhior deepens, he starts using intimate address ("thou") instead.
